# How do I check a cell with multiple values separated by commas for the nth letter in each element?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Sample Data:

I have a single cell:      (ABCD, HASDR, HGND, JHDDHS)

Another row would have     (ABDD, FADF, HGND)

I want to be able to check if the 4th letter of each element is the letter "D" or "F" and if ALL elements are true then it returns a string value, but the problem is that these values are in one cell. I tried text to column also but I don't know how to compare a row of data.

EDIT:

What if I wanted to check the 4th letter for the letter "D" or "F" ?
Tim thank you for everything so far, Im sure you are a very busy person so I appreciate all the help that I am getting from you.

Criteria:

If 4th letter in all elements is "D" or "F" then result is string "Result 1"

If 4th letter in all elements is "T" result is "Result 2"

If 4th letter in all elements is mixed group is mixed then result is "Mixed"

Sample:

```
ABCD,ABCD,ABCF= Result 1
ABCD,ABCD,ABCD= Result 1
ABCF,ABCF,ABCF= Result 1
ABCT,ABCT,ABCT= Result 2
ABCD,ABCD,ABCT = Mix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user-defined function:

```
Function GetResult(v)

    Dim arr, e, rv As String, p
    Dim nDF As Long, nT As Long, tot As Long

    v = Replace(v, "(", "") 'EDIT
    v = Replace(v, ")", "") 'EDIT

    arr = Split(v, ",")
    tot = UBound(arr) + 1 'number of values

    If tot > 0 Then
        rv = "Mixed" 'the default value
        For Each e In arr
            p = Mid(Trim(e), 4, 1)
            If p = "D" Or p = "F" Then nDF = nDF + 1
            If p = "T" Then nT = nT + 1
        Next e
        If nDF = tot Then rv = "Result 1"
        If nT = tot Then rv = "Result 2"
    End If

    GetResult = rv
End Function
```

You should be able to take it from here if you need to add more checks or change the logic a little...

Comment: Just tried it and returned as false. Should be true.

Comment: For some reason it only checks the first element in the array and it only works for the 3rd character

Comment: Does your cell content actually contain parentheses?  Works for me (without parentheses)

Comment: Yes I have parentheses. Which makes sense why 

(ABDS,FASD,HGSD)

would return a True Value because 1st element the D is technically the 4th character in the string.

Comment: Edited to remove the parentheses

Comment: What if I wanted to have the function return True for the letter "D" or "F" ?
How does the code change? Tim thank you for everything so far, Im sure you are a very busy person so I appreciate all the help that I am getting from you.

(ABSF,FASD,HGSD) = True 

to avoid all the back and forth I want to expand the question to basically result in the following way.

If 4th letter in element is "D" or "F" then result is string "Result 1"

Comment: I updated the original question to reflect what I need help with more clearly.

Comment: I apologize for being all over the place. Is there a way I can message you.

Comment: Edited - it saves a lot of time if you don't over-simplify your actual use case in your question: the best approach will vary depending on the real requirements...

Answer (score 1):

If there will always be a comma and a space in between the elements the following works to tell whether all of the elements contain the letter "D" and put true/false in adjacent cell (B1):

```
Sub CheckForTheD()

For x = 1 To Len(Range("A1").Value)
If Mid(Range("A1").Value, x, 1) = "," Then
    Y = Y + 1
    If Mid(Range("A1").Value, x + 5, 1) = "D" Then
        Z = Z + 1
    End If
End If
Next x

If Z = Y Then
Range("B1").Value = True
Else: Range("B1").Value = False
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for original data but how come when I try something like:

(ABOD01,ABOD02,ABOD03) 

the macro says false. In this case there are no spaces after the comma and its alpha numeric. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes, the above macro would only work for sequences that are separated by both a comma and a space however I believe Tim's macro above would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two examples you give are representative of all strings in question, i.e. that in each case the string is enclosed within parentheses and that the only delimiter is ", " (single comma followed by single space):

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(MID(","&A1&", αβγD",FIND(",",","&A1&", αβγD",ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))))+5,1)<>"D"))=0`

As per your new request:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(MMULT(0+(MID(","&A1&", αβγD",FIND(",",","&A1&", αβγD",ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))))+5,1)<>{"D","F"}),{1;1})<>1))=0`

Regards

Comment: How would I edit this formula to check if 4th letter is either a "D" or an "F"

 (ABCD, HASDR, HGND, JHDSHS) would return True also

Comment: Added a version to that effect. You're welcome, by the way.